# ngx datatable vertical scroll bar does not come back to start of page if there there are more records than defined page size

Tags: ngx-datatable

**Pre condition** -

1. Have `pagination`, `searchTerm`, and `vertical` scrolling implemented and works fine.
2. records to show per page = `25`

**Steps to reproduce**

1. User has searched for say '`batMan0`' in the list of 100 files. Let's say names are from `batMan001.txt` to `batMan099.txt`.
2. User then scrolls to say page 2 by grabbing scrollbar and pulling it down. Now total number of files on the table is = 50 ( `batMan001.txt` to `batMan050.txt`)
3. Now user refines the search term to `'batMa'`, (so that search result increases). Once the search is finished, pageNumber resets to 0. This is OK.

**The Problem -**
Problem is with scroll bar. It does not come back to first row of the table and stays at the same place where user has left on table last time. And because of this, the rows are not visible and user has to scroll up to see the table rows.

How can I fix this issue i.e. bring back the scroll bar to first position.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this? I've been tackling this problem for 2 days now and have run out of ideas on how to get the position reset.

Comment: Sorry. Not yet.

Comment: A suggestion would be that whenever the user finishes filtering something, so the rows in your table change, get the first row of the table as an HTML element and call scrollIntoView()